# In plotly line plot, is there a way to set plotly to not join the gaps between different labels?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, jupyter

I have attached a screenshot to my problem, but basically this is data of activity when the subject is awake and asleep, and the red is for when he is asleep. Is there a way to not have the blue lines connect to each other?

```
px.line(df["Axis1"], color = df["is_asleep"])
```

[screenshot of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqYhr.png)

Comment: I don't think so. I would probably split the awake df in 2.

Comment: You could use a [scatter plot](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) instead of a line plot. Since your data is labeled by time, a line connecting the points is optional.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to exclude holidays and certain times of the day has been added as a range-breaking feature. However, this is only effective when there is missing in one time series data, and in the example of your data, the first time series, the next time series, and the last time series would be drawn.
Since you did not present any data, I will create similar data to illustrate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.date_range('2022-06-01 00:00:00', '2022-06-01 12:00:00', freq='10min'), 'name':['a']*73, 'value': np.random.randint(0,3000,73)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.date_range('2022-06-01 12:00:00', '2022-06-02 00:00:00', freq='10min'), 'name':['br']*73, 'value': np.random.randint(0,1000,73)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.date_range('2022-06-02 00:00:00', '2022-06-02 12:00:00', freq='10min'), 'name':['a']*73, 'value': np.random.randint(0,3000,73)})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

import plotly.express as px

px.line(df, x=df['time'], y=df['value'], color='name')
```

[image]

```
 # use rangebreaks

fig = px.line(df, x=df['time'], y=df['value'], color='name')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=[12,0], pattern='hour')
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    mode='lines',
    x=df1['time'],
    y=df1['value'],
    line=dict(
        color='blue',
        width=2,
        ),
    name='a'
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    mode='lines',
    x=df2['time'],
    y=df2['value'],
    line=dict(
        color='red',
        width=2,
        ),
    name='br'
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    mode='lines',
    x=df3['time'],
    y=df3['value'],
    line=dict(
        color='blue',
        width=2,
        ),
    name='a',
    showlegend=False,
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]